# Recording KeyCommands in a round view like tweetie or things preferences

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon, keystrokes

How would you record the keystrokes in view and set them to the NSUserdefaults because every key has a numeric value and there are also modifier keys…how would u do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Waffle Software's Shortcut Recorder:  http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/
(And to toot my own horn) I've written a class to make registering shortcuts easier than using the Carbon API or a wrapper like PTHotKey:  http://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey